# Shortest path between all pairs of vertices in cyclic undirected weighted sparse graph

Tags: algorithms, graphs, shortest-path, efficiency

Is there any efficient algorithm to find shortest distance between **all pairs of vertices**?

The graph is:

- Cyclic
- Sparse (each vertex has either 2 or 3 edge)
- undirected(bidirectional)
- weighted
- non-negative

Since Floyd-Warshall algorithm and Johnson's algorithm are best for finding shortest path for every pairs but:

- Johnson's algorithm works on directed
- Floyd-Warshall algorithm is best for dense graphs

I couldn't find any algo that is efficient for above graph conditions.

Comment: If algorithm works on directed, it works on undirected as well (each non-directed edge can be converted to a pair of directed).

Comment: @rus9384 "non-directed edge can be converted to a pair of directed" --how?

Comment: If you have nondirected edge A---B, just replace it with A-->B and A<--B.

Answer (score 3):

Mikkel Thorup's paper [Undirected Single-Source Shortest Paths with Positive
Integer Weights in Linear Time](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/af26/5dd8ae14377016fa77ac82222b1c5f1af7ce.pdf) shows an $O(m)$ time algorithm for single-source shortest paths on undirected weighted graphs. That immediately implies an $O(mn)$ time algorithm for all pair shortest paths, which is the optimal $O(n^2)$ in your scenario.

Comment: The article seems to be paid and costly. Isn't any free link present?

Comment: @wrangler I edited it. Now it should be a free link.